# R: Writing a function which has as its input a vector

Tags: r

I started learning R recently and don't know how to write this:

Write a function which has as its input a vector where each element is a positive integer below 500 000 000, and which returns each element of the input vector which is a cube number.

When I got a single value x, I usually start with:

```
my.function <- function(x) {
```

However what if I want a vector as outlined above?
I was thinking of defining x as below:

```
my.function <- function(x) { 
x <- c(0<n<500000000)
```

but this does not work.
How can I do this?

Comment: You don't have to do anything to make the function take a vector. `function(x)` will take a vector.

Comment: It is not clear what you have already, and what you want. The vector with numbers < 500k is your argument, or is it created inside the function?

Comment: @vaettchen I think the vector with numbers <500k is my argument. I understand how to use a vector with a few elements for example: ` x <- c(1,2,3,4,5) `  . However, how can I apply the condition where each element in the vector is a positive integer below 500k? My intuition says ' x <- c(0<n<500k) ` where n is some arbitrary element.

Comment: Try `x <- runif( 10, 1, 500000000 )`

Comment: or `sample(1:500000000, 10)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
 x [ mapply( function(xx,yy) {isTRUE(all.equal(xx,yy))}, 
                 xx=(x) ^ (1/3) , 
                 yy=round(  (x) ^ (1/3), 0 ) ) ]

> x <- 1:512  # to get your desired range it would be `seq.int(500000000)`
> x[ mapply( function(xx,yy) {isTRUE(all.equal(xx,yy))}, 
                xx=(x) ^ (1/3) , 
                yy=round(  (x) ^ (1/3), 0 ) ) ]
[1]   1   8  27  64 125 216 343 512
```

I think that 500 000 000 is below integer.max or max.integer. You should check `.Machine`

(This is going to be slow. Better algorithms are possible and perhaps that is perhaps what your instructor wants.)

```
> x <- seq.int(50000)
> cubes
 [1]    1    8   27   64  125  216  343  512  729 1000 1331 1728 2197 2744 3375
[16] 4096 4913
> cubes <- x[ mapply( function(xx,yy) {isTRUE(all.equal(xx,yy))}, xx=(x) ^ (1/3) , yy=round(  (x) ^ (1/3), 0 ) ) ]
> cubes
 [1]     1     8    27    64   125   216   343   512   729  1000  1331  1728
[13]  2197  2744  3375  4096  4913  5832  6859  8000  9261 10648 12167 13824
[25] 15625 17576 19683 21952 24389 27000 29791 32768 35937 39304 42875 46656
```

I suspect this is linear in length of `x`

```
> x <- seq.int(500000)
> system.time( {cubes <- x[ mapply( function(xx,yy) {isTRUE(all.equal(xx,yy))}, xx=(x) ^ (1/3) , yy=round(  (x) ^ (1/3), 0 ) ) ] } )
   user  system elapsed 
105.455   1.110 107.138
```

This only require checking a relatively few values, since cube-root of your max is only 793 plus a fraction:

```
x[ x %in% (1:(max(x)^(1/3)) )^3]   # almost instantaneous with x <- 1:500000
#   ==== testing worst case scenario ====
> x <- 1:500000000
> system.time( {cubes <- x[ x %in% (1:(max(x)^(1/3)) )^3]})
   user  system elapsed 
 25.025   8.379  32.857   # that's in seconds
```

Comment: Thanks for this but it seems too complex. Essentially what I need is: 1. my.function <- function(x) {  2. Let x be all integers between 1 and 500000000  3. check every integer in that range and see if it is a cube number. 4. Print that number if it is a cube, do nothing if it is not. I hope this makes it a bit clearer since my initial example wasn't clear :)

Comment: I wrote an algorithm which checks if a given number (which I input) is a cube or not, but how do I make the algorithm print all cube numbers it finds in the range 1:500000000 ?

Comment: Oh sorry, just saw your edit, that second algorithm seems to be what I'm looking for!

Comment: Although my range is from 1 to 500 million, it seems to take a long time by using the above algorithm. Do you have any ideas how to speed this up?

Comment: I do. I can see a mechanism produce a remarkable improvement. But why should I invest the time? You don't seem to have found this even useful judging from the lack of an upvote.

Comment: I did upvote, but since I'm a new member my upvotes cannot be seen publicly yet.

Comment: Got it. Will post an improvement. (I think.)

Comment: Thanks. I do value very much your help

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to do anything differently in terms of creating the function as @Adam correctly states.

```
my_function = function(x){}
```

is all you need.

You can check whether the input fits your constraints after this point. For example:

```
my_function = function(x){
    if(!is.vector(x))
        stop("Not a vector")

    if(any(x < 0 | x > 500000))
        stop("Does not fit constraints")
}
```

Comment: I don't see that you interpreted the phrase "is a cube number". I interpreted it as is a perfect cube.

Comment: You can just add `x = x[sqrt(x) %% 1 == 0]` inside the function by @SamPassmore to only keep the perfect cube numbers.

Comment: @42 I only aimed to answer the question in the title. This strikes me as a homework assignment, and I did not want to offer the complete solution. Although your commitment to the question is admirable.